# Defining a let macro scope in emacs lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, elisp, metaprogramming

In emacs lisp (but answers relating to common lisp are also welcome) I have a library that uses a macro and I want to hijack one of the macro's arguments only when executed in a certain context. Essentially what I want is a macro:

```
; My macro. This is a sketch of what I want that doesn't work.
(defmacro hijack-f (body)
  `(macrolet ((f (x) `(f (+ 1 ,x))))
     ,@body))

; Defined in the library, I don't want to deal with these    
(defmacro f (x) x)
(defun g (x) (f x))
```

So that

```
(g 1) ; => 1
(hijack-f (g 1)) ; => 2
(hijack-f (hijack-f (g 1))) ; => 3
```

EDIT: @melpomene and @reiner-joswig correctly point out that `f` is expanded in `g` before `hijack-f`. As a followup is there a `hijack-f` such that:

```
(f 1) ; => 1
(hijack-f (f 1)) ; => 2
(hijack-f (hijack-f (f 1))) ; => 3
```

Comment: This won't work, since the code of G is not visible to the macro.

Comment: that's right, thanks. How about if I skip `g` and go straight for an expression of `f` (see edit)?

Comment: Is `f` really a *macro* and not a *function*?  Why?

Comment: It's in the library, actually it defines functions and variables etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want is not possible because `g` does not contain an invocation of `f`. Instead `f` runs *first* and expands to (part of) the definition of `g`.

That is:

```
(defun g (x) (f x))
```

immediately turns into

```
(defun g (x) x)
```

Which then defines `g` as a function (whose value is `(lambda (x) x)`).

Messing with `f` at runtime doesn't affect anything because its invocation is long gone by the time you call `g`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy for your `f` to be a function and not a macro, and to use CL not elisp, then you are after `flet` and a macro like this:

```
(defmacro hijack-f (&body body)
  `(flet ((f (x)
            (f (1+ x))))
     ,@body))
```

Given a global defintion of `f`:

```
(defun f (x)
  x)
```

Then

```
> (hijack-f (f 1))
2

> (hijack-f (hijack-f (f 1)))
3
```

And so on.

(As others have pointed out, you can't hijack code that has already been compiled with a macro like this: you would need to do it by having `f` cooperate in the hijacking.)